# How to get the image url from the AVCapturePhotoOutput?

Tags: swift

When I click on the button it captures the photo using AVCapturePhotoOutput and storing the URL in the database but when I capture the photo it gets black. I have uploaded the pic you can see it once.

[image]

```
let stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()


 @IBAction func capturephoto(_ sender: Any) {
    print("entered into capture photo")

    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat

    captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    print("stillimageoutput is",stillImageOutput)
    self.stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)




}
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {


        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            print("image: \(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size)") // Your Image
            //Here I should conver the dataImage into URL....

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no URL. What you have is the data itself. If you want the data to be saved to some URL then save it.

Comment: @matt - Thanks for the suggestion. I have solved the issue but the issue is the pic is getting black.

Comment: How do you know? None of the code you’ve shown displays the photo so how do we know what you’re doing now?

Answer (score 0):

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)
    }
}
```